# Make PHP code editable from within a textarea

Tags: php, jquery

I'm currently working on my custom CMS, and I want the administrator to be able to edit the php files and stylesheets in the public area. I have no problem getting to files, and have tried several ideas based on my findings as a result of Google-ing, and my, somewhat thorough, search of this site. Here's where I am so far:

Getting the files:

```
 <?php
    $dir = "./";
    function get_files($directory = "") {
    $dir = $directory;
    if(is_dir($dir)) {
            $dir_array = scandir($dir);
        $filtered = array();
        foreach($dir_array as $file) :
        if(stripos($file, '.') > 0)
                array_push($filtered, $file);
        endforeach;
        return $filtered;
    } else {
        //Do something else
           }
    }
```

Using jQuery to output the content of each file inside the textarea:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.file').each(function(){
    var file_link = this;
    var HTML_FILE_URL = './' + file_link.id;
    var file_id = file_link.id;
    $(file_link).bind('click', function(){
        $('#filename').text(" - " + file_id);
    $.get(HTML_FILE_URL, function(data){
                var htmlData = htmlEntities(data);
        $('textarea').text(htmlData);
        });
    });
    });
});


function htmlEntities(str) {
    //This is a function which I found on this site.
    //It gave me a good result on the html part
    //However, the PHP codes were already executed. 
}
```

I would very much appreciate it if any one could point me in the right direction. Is there any particular PHP method that I'm completely overlooking? Is there a solution I can refer to?

Thanks.

Comment: From a security perspective i would not allow editing php files from the cms, this could be dangerous.

Comment: Regardless of whether you get it working or not, I feel it is important to point out that this is a very very bad idea. Allowing arbitrary PHP code to be entered by the site administrator is about the biggest security risk you could put into your system. Even if the administrators are all trustworthy (are they?) and your password storage system is completely secure (is it? really? are you sure?), there are still any number of ways an attacker could use this feature to compromise your system.

Comment: Don't let anybody write `<?php rmdir || unlink || whatever` into your app, please. Nevertheless, if you want people to mess with your code and styles, just grant FTP access to them.

Comment: Even before I even tried doing this, I was warned about the security holes I'll be risking. Warning duly noted. Thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not directly load the source code from php files via javascript - as you have found the php is always executed.

What you need to do is call a php script that will load and return the source code:

```
//getsource.php
$editable_files = array('edit1.php', 'mybooks.php');

if(isset($_GET['file']) && in_array($_GET['file'], $editable_files)){
    echo file_get_contents($_GET['file']);
}
```

Then you would call this file in your js.

As others have mentioned, this could open up a number of security vulnerabilities, but that is beyond the scope of this question

Comment: Thanks. I know I'm putting security at risk. I would surely look more into the security aspects. But, for now, making it work is crucial.

Comment: @user3489312 Sure, so did my answer help you? Or do you still have problems?